# How to split a data frame of strings into multiple columns based on a list of indexes with pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have  a data frame that is  made up of strings, I'd like to split each string into multiple columns based on a list of indices. I have tried using str.extract approach and was successful, but i was wondering if there is an efficient way to do this (eg. pass a list of indexes )

```
df = pd.DataFrame(['100000037031061620140520173', '200002823676010220150420181','200004493595011020150720181'])
df2_test = df[0].str.extract('(.{6})(.{6})(.{8})(.{6})(.{1})') #i'd like to pass the list of positions to split into columns
positions = [6,6,8,6,1]
```

Comment: Do the positions define the index at which the split is to be made for each string?

Comment: that is right @ Shaunak Sen

Comment: What is the expected output you are looking for?

Comment: I am looking for the same output that I get using str.extract (df2_test), but instead of manually typing in the positions, I'd like to pass a list that has indexes where the split is to be made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without regex if you like , we can do using [`series.str.slice()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.slice.html):

```
idx= [0] + [*np.cumsum(positions)]
#[0, 6, 12, 20, 26, 27]
slices = [(a,b) for a,b in zip(idx,idx[1:])]
#[(0, 6), (6, 12), (12, 20), (20, 26), (26, 27)]
pd.concat([df[0].str.slice(*i).rename(e) for e,i in enumerate(slices)],axis=1)
```

---

```
        0       1         2       3  4
0  100000  037031  06162014  052017  3
1  200002  823676  01022015  042018  1
2  200004  493595  01102015  072018  1
```